# Execute Insert statement depending of rows obtained from select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement like

```
SELECT
    [TaskStatusName],
    [TaskTypeName],
    [TaskId]
FROM
    [TaskStatusAudit]
WHERE
    [TaskId] IN
    (
        SELECT
            [T].[TaskId]
        FROM
            [Task] AS [T]
        WHERE
            [T].[DesignKey] = @LastDesignKeyOfProject
            AND
            [TaskStatusId] != @PendingStatus
            AND
            [TaskStatusId] != @CompletedStatus
    )
```

Below this I have a insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [TaskStatusAudit]
(
    [TaskStatusAuditId],
    [Date],
    [EmpGuid],
    [TaskStatusName],
    [TaskTypeName],
    [TaskId]
)
VALUES
(
    @TaskStatusName,
    @TaskTypeName,
    @TaskId
)
```

My question is, how can I execute that insert foreach value or row I'm getting in my first select? Regards

**UPDATE**

As comments below I try to do as:

```
  DECLARE @TaskStatusName VARCHAR(255)
                , @TaskTypeName   VARCHAR(255)
                , @TaskId         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

     --Assigning pararameters
   SELECT
                 @TaskStatusName = 'COMPLETED'
                , @TaskTypeName = [TaskTypeName]
                , @TaskId = [T].[TaskId]
                 FROM [TaskStatusAudit] AS [TSA]
                     INNER JOIN [Task] AS [T] ON [T].[DesignKey] = @LastDesignKeyOfProject
                                            AND [T].[TaskStatusId] != @PendingStatus
                                            AND [T].[TaskStatusId] != @CompletedStatus
            -- using parameters to insert
            INSERT INTO [TaskStatusAudit]
            (
                 [TaskStatusAuditId]
                , [Date]
                , [EmpGuid]
                , [TaskStatusName]
                , [TaskTypeName]
                , [TaskId]
            )
            VALUES
                (
                 NEWID()
                , @Today
                , @CreatedBy
                , @TaskStatusName
                , @TaskTypeName
                , @TaskId
                )
```

I run it but it only insert one row instead multiple. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint:  Put the `INSERT` clause before the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM`.

Also, I simplified your `SELECT` to use an `INNER JOIN` instead of `WHERE x IN ( SELECT y )`.

```
INSERT INTO [TaskStatusAudit] 
(
    [TaskStatusAuditId],
    [Date],
    [EmpGuid],
    [TaskStatusName],
    [TaskTypeName],
    [TaskId]
)
SELECT
    @auditId,
    GETUTCDATE(),
    @empGuid
    [TaskStatusName],
    [TaskTypeName],
    [TaskId]
FROM
    [TaskStatusAudit] AS A
    INNER JOIN [Task] ON
        [Task].DesignKey = @LastDesignKeyOfProject AND
        A.[TaskStatusId] != @PendingStatus AND
        A.[TaskStatusId] != @CompletedStatus
```

Comment: @JuanPedro I suggest you try my `INSERT` query first and tell me if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters store single values. It will insert only one as expected. The code below should work;

```
INSERT INTO [TaskStatusAudit]
(
     [TaskStatusAuditId]
    ,[Date]
    ,[EmpGuid]
    ,[TaskStatusName]
    ,[TaskTypeName]
    ,[TaskId]
)            
    SELECT
        NEWID(), 
        GETDATE(),
        @CreatedBy,
        'COMPLETED',
        [TaskTypeName]
        [TaskId]
        FROM [TaskStatusAudit] AS [TSA]
            INNER JOIN [Task] AS [T] ON [T].[DesignKey] = @LastDesignKeyOfProject
                                AND [T].[TaskStatusId] != @PendingStatus
                                AND [T].[TaskStatusId] != @CompletedStatus
```

You can check the syntax for 'INSERT INTO SELECT' from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: I try it but I getting: "The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns" but there are the same number of items! what a hell!

Comment: @JuanPedro Make sure that each column in Insert statement should match to the ones in Select statement. For example; [TaskStatusAuditId]=>NEWID(), [Date] => GETDATE() ...etc.